# How to merge path with pycairo?

Tags: python, cairo, pycairo

I am drawing with *pycairo* using curve_to  , here's the code :

```
ctx.move_to(0.4,0.8)
ctx.curve_to(0.3,0.4 ,0.4,0.4 ,0.4,0.4)
ctx.set_source_rgb(0,0,0)
ctx.set_line_width(0.001)
ctx.fill()

ctx.move_to(0.4,0.8)
ctx.line_to(0.5,0.8)
ctx.set_source_rgb(0,0,0)
ctx.set_line_width(0.001)
ctx.stroke()


ctx.move_to(0.5,0.8)
ctx.curve_to(0.6,0.4 ,0.5,0.4 ,0.5,0.4)
ctx.set_source_rgb(0,0,0)
ctx.set_line_width(0.001)
ctx.fill()

ctx.move_to(0.4,0.4)
ctx.line_to(0.5,0.4)
ctx.set_source_rgb(0,0,0)
ctx.set_line_width(0.001)
ctx.stroke()
```

[image]

i'm want to fill the object but as you see , i cannot fill it all because they're separate and not merged yet. So i think the closest approach here is to merge them .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
    ctx.set_source_rgb(0,0,0)
    ctx.set_line_width(0.001)

    ctx.move_to(0.5,0.8)
    ctx.line_to(0.4,0.8)
    ctx.curve_to(0.3,0.4 ,0.4,0.4 ,0.4,0.4)

    ctx.move_to(0.4,0.4)
    ctx.line_to(0.5,0.8)
    ctx.curve_to(0.6,0.4 ,0.5,0.4 ,0.5,0.4)

    ctx.fill()
```

I tested it this and it formed a filled region. I'm not sure its right.

Comment: yeah i tested it too and it works , what i did was put the lines separately , and you put the bottom/top border one with left/right border